# SSL3_GET_KEY_EXCHANGE:wrong signature length

Tags: curl, ssl, libcurl

I am trying to establish https connection using libcurl to web-site with valid SSL sertificate, which was issued by one of the authorities.

I got cacert.pem from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Here is the code I am using:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO , "./cacert.pem");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, parse_response);

curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

here is the output I am getting:

> - About to connect() to HOST_ADDRESS_IS_HERE port 443 (#0)
> - Trying HOST_IP_IS_HERE...
> - Adding handle: conn: 0x153d68
> - Adding handle: send: 0
> - Adding handle: recv: 0
> - Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
> - - Conn 0 (0x153d68) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
> - Connected to HOST_ADDRESS_IS_HERE (HOST_IP_IS_HERE) port 443 (#0)
> - successfully set certificate verify locations:
> - CAfile: ./cacert.pem   CApath: none
> - error:1408D108:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_KEY_EXCHANGE:wrong signature length
> - Closing connection 0

Thank you very much for your time in advance!

Comment: What is the URL of the site?

Comment: @jww it is a company web-site, so I can't reveal it; should I check anything specific? thanks.